# How to make generic function in database HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

can you please tell me how to make generic function in database HTML5.It mean I will pass name of "Table" .Or If possible we can pass column names of table with data type ?

Can you please give example of that ?

I am getting error while using 
http://jsfiddle.net/RnheY/1/

```
var html5rocks = {};
html5rocks.webdb = {};
html5rocks.webdb.db = null;
html5rocks.webdb.open = function() {
 var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
  html5rocks.webdb.db = openDatabase("DataBaseName", "1.0", "Todo manager", dbSize);
}


html5rocks.webdb.createTable = function(tableName) {
  var db = html5rocks.webdb.db;

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT, added_on DATETIME)", []);
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
      html5rocks.webdb.open();
  html5rocks.webdb.createTable("Student");
});
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an array and defining it on global level.
Please find the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JvJ/)

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" value="Rohit">
<input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" value="Password">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" data-mini="true">
```

**JQUERY SCRIPTS**

```
var arrcolumnName = ['UserName', 'Password'];
var tablename = 'tbl_Login'


$('#submit').click(function () {
    submitForm();
});

function submitForm() {
    var _UserName = $('#UserName').val();
    var _Password = $('#Password').val();
    var arrValue = _UserName + '|' + _Password;
    var arr = arrValue.split("|");
    InsertIntoTable(tablename, arrcolumnName, arr);
 }

function InsertQuery(tablename, arrColumn, arrValues) {
    var query = "";
    query += "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " (";
    for (i = 0; i < arrColumn.length; i++)
    query += arrColumn[i] + ",";

    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
    query += ") VALUES ("
    for (i = 0; i < arrValues.length; i++)
    query += "'" + arrValues[i] + "',";
    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
    query += ")"
    return query;
}


function InsertIntoTable(tablename, arrColumn, arrValue) {
    var db = CreateDB();
    var Query = InsertQuery(tablename, arrColumn, arrValue)
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorDB, successDB);

function populateDB(tx) {
    CreateTable(tablename, arrcolumnName, tx);
    tx.executeSql(Query);
}

function errorDB(err) {
    alert(err.message);
}

function successDB() {
    alert('Insert Success!!!');
}
}


function CreateDB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase('TrialDB1', '', 'my first database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    return db;
}

function CreateTable(tablename, arrColumn, tx) {
    var Query = CreateTableQuery(tablename, arrColumn);
    tx.executeSql(Query);
}

function CreateTableQuery(tablename, arrColumn) {
    var query = "";
    query += "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tablename + " (";
    for (i = 0; i < arrColumn.length; i++)
    query += arrColumn[i] + ",";

    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
    query += ")"
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is difficult to answer since we don't know where to get the values from.

I suggest you to make an adjustment to the createTable function (you can pass in later what you want):

```
html5rocks.webdb.createTable = function(tableName, fields) {
  var db = html5rocks.webdb.db;

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tableName+"("+fields+")", []);
  });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
html5rocks.webdb.createTable("Student", "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT, added_on DATETIME");
```

**Be aware that WebDB lost from IndexedDB in becoming the new HTML5 standard for client databases. You should use IndexedDB.**

Answer (score 0):

We have created query where we pass tablename and array of columns, I have modified the function for you which takes other third paramater i.e datatype

```
function CreateQuery(tablename, arrColumn,arrDataType) {
    var query = "";
    query += "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tablename + " (";
    for (i = 0; i < arrColumn.length; i++)
        query += arrColumn[i] + " " + arrDataType[i] + ",";

    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
    query += ")"
    return query;
}
```