# Creating a persistent db in Html5 mobile app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have created a simple Jquery mobile app. A one page app that navigate between divs. The app is meant to create a simple database when it is launched so users can register. After registration users details is store into the db created.
So the next time the app is launched the app can go and check the db created and display the home screen if thee user has registered.

But my challenge is that Each time I launch the app. it refreshes and re-creates an empty database. so even when the user registers I loss the registration details.
Is there a way I can create a persistent db in jQuery mobile that would not clear when a user refreshes the app.
My code is below:

```
if(window.openDatabase) {
  //This is going to open and create the database
  db = window.openDatabase('mydb','1.0' ,'My First Database', 2* 1024*1024);
}
```

This is how I create my db.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724530/how-to-make-generic-function-in-databse-html5/21725508#21725508 hope this link helps